# Arc miter bevel creates miters on straight edges

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I came across strange artifacts after adding a bevel modifier to a keycap model. When I set the inner miter type to 'Arc,' some vertices have a miter applied despite the adjacent edges meeting in a straight line. This seems counter to the [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html#geometry):

> A miter is formed when two beveled edges meet at an angle.

I found it very easy to reproduce this issue without any manual modeling:

- Start with a cube
- Add a subdivision surface modifier set to 'Simple' and increase the subdivisions to 3
- Add a bevel modifier with limit method set to 'Angle' and inner miter type set to 'Arc'

The model I originally encountered the problem on is a deformed subdivided cube. The same problem occurs regardless of whether I use modifiers or tools to create the subdivisions and bevels. I can understand why Blender might add a miter to a curved edge like the top of the keycap, but it ignored that edge. It seems to add them totally at random.

I have tested from scratch on Blender 2.82 and 2.90. Why is this happening? Is there anything I can do to mitigate it, besides applying the modifier and cleaning up?

[image: The model with its bevel modifier settings.]

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's a good one :). It's also weirdly changing with face size https://imgur.com/a/KDH836K. I'd report it as a bug

Comment: I have done [just that](https://developer.blender.org/T82120). I will keep updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange behaviour in question was [a confirmed bug](https://developer.blender.org/T82120) and has since been resolved. In the latest version of Blender ([2.92.0 alpha](https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.92.0-0c4d12986a74-windows64.zip)) the issue is absent.

If you are having the same issue, update Blender.